# What type of batteries are used in smart wristband?

Tags: electrical-engineering, battery

I'm making one project for my class, some kind of smart wristband, but not sure which type of battery should I use. I found a lot of good wristband online, I see that they usually have 60 - 100mAh batteries.

Can someone tell the type of batteries used in Smart wristbands?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like smart wristbands are using  lithium polymer batteries. Here are some examples.

- Jawbone UP24 JL01-52M-US - Bluetooth 4.0 Wristband - **32 mAh Li-ion polymer**
- Xiaomi Mi Band XMSH01HM - Bluetooth 4.0 Fitness Wristband - **3.7 V, 41 mAh Li-Polymer**
- Atlas Wristband A101 - **3.7 V, 120 mAh, Li-Polymer**
- Amzer FitZer KA - Bluetooth Activity Tracker - **3.7 V, 70 mAh, Li-Polymer**

---

**References:**

- [Jawbone UP24 JL01-52M-US - Bluetooth 4.0 Wristband](http://techinsights.com/reports-and-subscriptions/open-market-reports/Report-Profile/?ReportKey=10045)
- [Xiaomi Mi Band XMSH01HM - Bluetooth 4.0 Fitness Wristband](http://techinsights.com/reports-and-subscriptions/open-market-reports/Report-Profile/?ReportKey=10231)
- [Atlas Wristband A101 - Bluetooth Activity Tracker](http://www.techinsights.com/reports-and-subscriptions/open-market-reports/Report-Profile/?ReportKey=11211)
- [Amzer FitZer KA - Bluetooth Activity Tracker](http://www.techinsights.com/reports-and-subscriptions/open-market-reports/Report-Profile/?ReportKey=11259)
- [Teardown Reports](http://www.techinsights.com/teardown.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As Mahendra's answer indicates just about all of the commercial smart bands use Li-something based batteries.

However if this is for a class project I'd recommend using something like a CR2032. If you buy a bulk pack then they are relatively cheap and hold about 200mAh each.
For testing and development you can easily replace the battery holder with a wired connection to two AA batteries to prevent burning through too many batteries.

Your end product won't be rechargeable but as a class project you probably don't want to spend half of your time designing battery charging and monitoring circuits.